# Can use a function once, not twice, get undefined second time

Tags: google-apps-script

EDIT : fixed dummy data, thanks for your comment.

I want to create a series of functions to create emails. I need to remove some parts of the input, but keep some others.

The general idea is : keep only the first name, return string from beginning until a space char. BUT, if there is a "particle" at the beginning of the lastname, return the string with the particle until the next space.

There is a regex builder to create a big regex that matches the interesting part of the name

This first snippet launches the `users()` function. I've put some hardcoded data to work with, but it should be extracted from a google spreadsheet. I get an error if I use the `oneName()` function twice (see next snippet for a single use example)

> Cannot read property '1' of undefined"

```js
users();

function users() {
  var data = [['Jean', 'A Marca'], ['Marie', 'A Marca von Machin'], ['Pierre-Philippe', 'A Marca von machin'], ['Charles-Henri', 'Machin von Truc'], ['Franz Albert', 'All\'Arrabiata von truc'], ['Jérôme', 'all\'arrabiata truc'], ['Heinz', 'n\'Goye'], ['Anne-Méry', 'M\'Bala'], ['Angel', 'Di Maria y Fôdes'], ['Herberto', 'Fôdes y Dos Santos']]
  
  var output = [];
  for(i in data){
    var prenom = oneName(data[i][0])[0];
    console.log(prenom);
    var nom = oneName(data[i][1])[0]
    console.log(nom);
  }
}

function oneName(nom) {
var particules1 = ['de ', 'di ', 'da ', 'dos ', 'von ', 'del\'', 'dell\'', 'della ', 'el ', 'al ', 'd\'', 'do ', 'du ', 'des ', 'de la ', 'a ', 'all\'', 'l\'', 'n\'', 'm\''];
  var particules2 = ['de',  'di',  'da',  'dos',  'von',  'del',   'dell',   'della',  'el',  'al',  'd',   'do',  'du',  'des',  'dela',   'a',  'all' ,  'l',   'n',   'm'];
  
  var regex = new RegExp(regexBuilder(particules1), 'gi');
  return nom.match(regex);
}


function regexBuilder(listeParticules){
  var regex = '';
  for(i in listeParticules){
    if(i == listeParticules.length -1){
      regex = regex + '(^' + listeParticules[i] + '[a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u024f\u1e00-\u1eff]+)|(^[a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u024f\u1e00-\u1eff\']+)';  
    }else{
      regex = regex + '(^' + listeParticules[i] + '[a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u024f\u1e00-\u1eff]+)|';
    }
  }
  return regex;
}
```

If I only use the oneName() function, everything is fine...

```js
users();

function users() {
  var data = [['Jean', 'A Marca'], ['Marie', 'A Marca von Machin'], ['Pierre-Philippe', 'A Marca von machin'], ['Charles-Henri, Machin von Truc'], ['Franz Albert', 'All\'Arrabiata von truc'], ['Jérôme', 'all\'arrabiata truc'], ['Heinz', 'n\'Goye'], ['Anne-Méry', 'M\'Bala'], ['Angel', 'Di Maria y Fôdes'], ['Herberto', 'Fôdes y Dos Santos']]
  
  var output = [];
  for(i in data){
    var prenom = oneName(data[i][0])[0];
    console.log(prenom);
  }
}

function oneName(nom) {
var particules1 = ['de ', 'di ', 'da ', 'dos ', 'von ', 'del\'', 'dell\'', 'della ', 'el ', 'al ', 'd\'', 'do ', 'du ', 'des ', 'de la ', 'a ', 'all\'', 'l\'', 'n\'', 'm\''];
  var particules2 = ['de',  'di',  'da',  'dos',  'von',  'del',   'dell',   'della',  'el',  'al',  'd',   'do',  'du',  'des',  'dela',   'a',  'all' ,  'l',   'n',   'm'];
  
  var regex = new RegExp(regexBuilder(particules1), 'gi');
  return nom.match(regex);
}


function regexBuilder(listeParticules){
  var regex = '';
  for(i in listeParticules){
    if(i == listeParticules.length -1){
      regex = regex + '(^' + listeParticules[i] + '[a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u024f\u1e00-\u1eff]+)|(^[a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u024f\u1e00-\u1eff\']+)';  
    }else{
      regex = regex + '(^' + listeParticules[i] + '[a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u024f\u1e00-\u1eff]+)|';
    }
  }
  return regex;
}
```

I have an additional issue : if I use the `oneName()` function only once, but I would like to use it to extract the lastnames, it works with the first three names, but get "`undefined`" again. This issue must have something to do with my regex, I'll try to troubleshoot it separately.

So, why can't I use this function twice ?

Comment: The error is probably because `['Charles-Henri, Machin von Truc']` is only one element. It should be `['Charles-Henri', 'Machin von Truc']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [Diego's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991957/can-use-a-function-once-not-twice-get-undefined-second-time#comment98631817_55991957) is one of the important modification points.

As another modification point, In your script, after `var prenom = oneName(data[i][0])[0]` was run, `data[i]` becomes `undefined` because `i` of `for(i in data){}` is used as the global. After `var prenom = oneName(data[i][0])[0];` was run, the value of `i` is changed in the function of `regexBuilder()`. By this, I think that the error occurs.

In order to avoid this error, how about this modification? In this modification, `for(i in data){` was modified to `for(var i in data){`. Please think of this as just two of several answers.

### Modified script:

```js
users();

function users() {
  var data = [['Jean', 'A Marca'], ['Marie', 'A Marca von Machin'], ['Pierre-Philippe', 'A Marca von machin'], ['Charles-Henri', 'Machin von Truc'], ['Franz Albert', 'All\'Arrabiata von truc'], ['Jérôme', 'all\'arrabiata truc'], ['Heinz', 'n\'Goye'], ['Anne-Méry', 'M\'Bala'], ['Angel', 'Di Maria y Fôdes'], ['Herberto', 'Fôdes y Dos Santos']]
  
  var output = [];
  for (var i in data) { // or for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // <--- Modified
    var prenom = oneName(data[i][0])[0];
    console.log(prenom);
    var nom = oneName(data[i][1])[0];
    console.log(nom);
  }
}

function oneName(nom) {
  var particules1 = ['de ', 'di ', 'da ', 'dos ', 'von ', 'del\'', 'dell\'', 'della ', 'el ', 'al ', 'd\'', 'do ', 'du ', 'des ', 'de la ', 'a ', 'all\'', 'l\'', 'n\'', 'm\''];
  var particules2 = ['de',  'di',  'da',  'dos',  'von',  'del',   'dell',   'della',  'el',  'al',  'd',   'do',  'du',  'des',  'dela',   'a',  'all' ,  'l',   'n',   'm'];
  var regex = new RegExp(regexBuilder(particules1), 'gi');
  return nom.match(regex);
}

function regexBuilder(listeParticules) {
  var regex = '';
  for(var i in listeParticules){ // Modified
    if(i == listeParticules.length -1){
      regex = regex + '(^' + listeParticules[i] + '[a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u024f\u1e00-\u1eff]+)|(^[a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u024f\u1e00-\u1eff\']+)';  
    }else{
      regex = regex + '(^' + listeParticules[i] + '[a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u024f\u1e00-\u1eff]+)|';
    }
  }
  return regex;
}
```

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: thank you @Tanaike. You solved it. I've learnt something here : an iteration variable can be "touched" by another in another function... That's a bit strange. My code was almost good, but I would never have found this alone.

Comment: @Romain Schmid Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.